# Google Cloud Console - Flask - main.py vs package

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask

OK, so I have been through some tutorials to get a flask app onto google cloud, which is fine.

I have also been through the flask tutorial to build a flaskr blog:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/

It occurred to me that a sensible thing to do would be to create a database (MySQL in mycase) on google and then modify the code so that it uses that.   This is fine and I can get it to work on my local machine.

However, now that I am coming to deploying this, I have hit a problem.

The google cloud tutorials tend to use a flask app that is initiated in a single file such as main.py, eg:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
....
```

The flask tutorial mentioned above uses a package and puts the code to create_app() in the __init__.py file and at present I cannot get this to start in the same way.   (see sample code).

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev'
    )
```

Are there some adjustments that I need to make to something like the app.yaml file to get it to recognise flask as the flaskr package or do I need to rewrite the whole thing so that it uses a main.py file ?

I feel that this is one of the points in time where I could really pick up a bad habit.   What in general is the preferred way to write flask apps on google cloud ?

I am using the standard environment in google.

Thanks for your advice.

Mark

Answer (score 3):

Since you have an application factory, you can create the app anywhere. Just create it in `main.py`, since this is what App Engine expects:

```py
from my_package import create_app

app = create_app()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.   I must admit that I found something on google cloud indicating that by default it looks for something like main.py to start flask, so you cannot use the package by default.   For this reason I started doing what you suggested, however I have had to change the code a bit because it looks for the templates and static files in the parent directory and not the package.   I think it is also possible to start the server with a different command line argument and hence a different directory, but I didn't really like the look of that.   My view is try to keep things simple.

Comment: I totally agree with you, It should be a simple and elegant way to achieve this. In this case, I recommend contacting GAE customer service (https://cloud.google.com/contact/). Please let me know if you solved the problem, thanks!