# How to deploy a Flask app to Google Cloud (App Engine) with an application factory, and how to write the app.yaml file?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

[I found a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283593/google-cloud-console-flask-main-py-vs-package) but the solution did not work for me.

I have written a Flask app by following the official tutorial. I am trying to deploy it with Google App Engine. I have used Blueprints. The directory structure of my app looks like this:

```
app
│   .gcloudignore
│   app.yaml
│   main.py
│   requirements.txt
│   __init__.py
│
├───googleutils
│   │   utils.py
│
├───home
│   │   home.py
│   │
│   ├───static
│   ├───templates
│   │       home.html
│
├───models
│   │   Message.py
│   │   User.py
│
├───profile
│   │   profile.py
│   │
│   ├───static
│   ├───templates
│   │       edit_message.html
│   │       profile.html
│
├───sessions
│   │   sessions.py
│   │
│   ├───templates
│   │       login.html
│   │       logout.html
│   │       register.html
│
├───static
│       style.css
│
├───templates
│       layout.html
│       wrapper.html
```

In my app directory I have my `app.yaml` and `requirements.txt`. I used `pip freeze` in my venv and just chucked everything it spat out into `requirements.txt`.

The current Flask tutorial instructs you to start your app via command line using `flask run`. Hence, my application starts from `__init__.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    # Application imports
    from .home import home
    from .sessions import sessions
    from .profile import profile

    # Blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(home.home_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(sessions.sessions_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(profile.profile_bp)

    return app
```

However, as noted in the question I linked above, gcloud looks for a `main.py`, so I added this to my root:

```py
from app import create_app

app = create_app()
```

At the moment I'm just trying to get my index loaded, which is defined in `home.py`:

```py
@home_bp.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
...
```

Here's my app.yaml:

```
runtime: python39
entrypoint: gunicorn "app:create_app()"

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Truth be told I have no idea how to write this file, especially for directories with variables, such as this one defined in `profile.py`:

```py
@profile_bp.route('/profile/<string:user_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def profile(user_id):
...
```

When I run `gcloud app deploy`, I get a 500 Server Error when I view my site in-browser, "The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what `app.yaml` does so maybe this doesn't apply, but it looks like your `main.py` is missing `if __name__ == '__main__': app.run()`. (This may not make a difference either but personally I always put `main.py` in the root folder, on the same level as the `app` directory as opposed to inside it)

Comment: app.yaml files are required for deploying apps to Google App Engine. Adding those lines unfortunately didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Did you check in the logs to see the reason behind the 500 error? You should also be able to see a traceback in your logs to see where in your code the error occurred from.

Comment: I looked everywhere for a log but couldn't find any. Where is it?

Comment: You have to go to https://console.cloud.google.com, select your project and on the menu (on your left hand side), there should be an entry for Logs. Use the ```Legacy Log Viewer``` in the sub menu as that one is easier to understand

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The log viewer and legacy log viewers were very slow and would sometimes fail to show me any errors one minute and show me lots the next. However, your comment did let me discover the Error Reporting page which was much clearer and helped me solve my issue, so thanks for that!

Comment: A tip for you - next time, just use an application skeleton from Google i.e. search for something like 'Google App Engine Python 3 Sample Application' and it will most likely show you a sample app from Google (on Github). You can also use a GAE GUI which usually comes with an Application Skeleton for their supported languages (we have one, check my profile for a link to the website)

Comment: We were given the GCP repository to help us, but the GAE examples all use the old Flask syntax where the app object is instantiated globally as opposed to within the create_app() function. I did search GitHub for GAE Flask apps containing "create_app()", but it wasn't helpful for a GAE Python/Flask beginner like me. I didn't know GAE GUI's were a thing and I will definitely use them (or yours) in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. My directory structure was wrong. It SHOULD be:

```py
│   app.yaml
│   main.py
│   requirements.txt
├───app
│   │   __init__.py
│   └
```

Where `app.yaml` contains only:

```
runtime: python39

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Which causes GCloud to automatically look for the `main.py` file containing:

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()
```

The whole webapp works this way.